# Como faço para eliminar a "sombra" do focus de uma <button></button>?

Tags: html, css

Depois de clicar no botão este fica com um efeito de sombra (azulado) à volta do mesmo... Deixo uma imagem para que percebam a minha dúvida.

[image]

Como remover essa linha exterior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O botão fica focado.

Use CSS:

```
*:focus{
    outline:0;
}
```

Comment: "Problema" resolvido.
Agradeço a tua disponibilidade.